# Compiler warning for missing xml comment for WCF service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, documentation

I have a C# project in VS 2010 that has WCF service references and we are getting a lot of warnings for XML documentation. I could add #pragma disable warning 1591 for the reference.cs files but would like a generic solution

I have come across http://lvquoc.blogspot.com/2010/11/disable-xml-comment-warning-in-workflow.html, where Quoc explained neatly how to do it WF generated code so was wondering if we could do something similar in this case, but couldn't get the build targets for WCF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently ran into this as well. When you generate your service reference make sure it is marked as internal instead of public.

The validation will no longer apply.

Answer (score -1):

You can surpress them in the build tab of your project's properties by entering 1591 in "Suppress Warnings".

Comment: But that would suppress those warnings for custom code too, which I do not want